# Snort Unknown Classtype Fatal Error

Tags: snort

When I add the rules file into Snort, I get the following mistakes. How can I solve this problem?

ERROR: /etc/snort/./rules/community.rules(18) Unknown ClassType: misc-activity
Fatal Error, Quitting..

How can i add classtype?

Comment: Refer to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176518/snort-priority-range?noredirect=1#comment340329_176518

Comment: i asked why i get this error. I added classtype in config file. But i got this error.

Comment: Can you post here your snort.config file. Most of the time, these errors indicate that snort cannot find/access .rules file